# Checking for non-integer input with >> chain (C++)

Tags: c++, file, error-handling, extract, cin

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int Width = 0;
  int Height = 0;

  cout << "Input filename: ";
  cin >> filename;
  cout << "Input width and height: ";
  cin >> Width >> Height;


//check if input is non-integer

   if (!cin) {
    cout << "Error: width is a non-integer value" << endl;
    exit(1); }

  else if (!cin) {
    cout << "Error: height is a non-integer value" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
```

I am trying to check if width and height are int inputs or not. With this code, I keep getting 
"Error: width is a non-integer value" even if the width is indeed an integer and I enter in a non-int for height. In what way could I simply check to see if these inputs are ints or not without encountering this error? Thanks!

Comment: You have to check for each input individually: `std::cin>>Width; if (!cin) {/*..*/}` `std::cin>>Height; if (!cin) {/*..*/}`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to allow the user to enter any type of value, then it is best to fetch these in `std::string`. Then you can do any sort of validation for provided input.

```
bool IsValidInt(const std::string & str)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit (str[i]))
        {
            // If a single non-digit character is found, 
            // then provided input is not integer
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then at the time of fetching input from user you could do something like this:

```
std::string heightStr;
cin >> heightStr
if(IsValidInt(heightStr))
{
    // If input has all digits, convert to int
    int height = stoi(heightStr);
}
else
{
    cout << "Error: width is a non-integer value" << endl;
}
```